# We good to participate in Winter Bash 2013?

Tags: discussion, event, winterbash

Details here: http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

We can opt out/in see we see fit. Personally, moar fun!

Comment: I don't see why not. As long as I get me some hats!

Comment: I'm in, let'S do it.

Comment: Let's do it! I might not find any of the hats, but it'll be fun to see it happen! :)

Comment: I'm super late to this - but yes! Let's do it!

Comment: Haha…there is even an [opt out](http://files.classyllama.com/694f0868/Magento_Stack_Exchange_185FDDDA.png) for the grinches!